# Question regarding rtl_fm and specific USB port connections

Tags: usb, kernel, python, c

I am planning to use 2 RTL-SDR dongles on a single computer. The thing is, they will be operating on 2 different frequencies, and so different antennas will be used.

I would like one instance of rtl_fm or gnuradio to open set to "frequency 1" and connect to a specific USB port. Then the other instance on "frequency 2" to another USB port.

I know that in Linux, USB ports are defined at a kernel level as such:
"The name given to this device by the kernel (KERNELS=="1-4.5") indicates that this device is plugged into the fifth port of a hub connected to port four on bus 1"

The computer I am using has no hub, and only one bus. It has 4 ports. So I would like to use 1-3.1 and 1-4.1 for example.

Can someone help me for this?

Thank you

Comment: When you enter `dmesg -w` in a terminal _before_ connecting the dongles, it will tell you some information about the specific dongle (like `idVendor`, `idProduct` and `SerialNumber`. You may use these informations to vreate a `udev` rule to handle the dongles regardless of the USB port.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, all dongles have the same serial number...

Comment: If you nevertheless want to reflect to the USB port, look in `/sys/devices` (search for `1-4.5`, e.g.).

Comment: How can I tell rtl_fm to start using only this specific port?

Comment: @ridgy here is the software I want to use: https://github.com/th0ma5w/rtl_fm_python Is there some sort of prefix or suffix I can add to a python script to force it to see only a specific usb port?

Comment: I don't know rtl_fm, and from the man page there is no way to tell the device. I found [this issue](https://github.com/AlbrechtL/welle.io/issues/95), which seems to not allow more than one dongle...

Comment: In the manpage it talks about -d (device index), could it be this?

Comment: So I have an old manpage. "device index" means to use the first, second, ... device; which one will be which may depend on the bus or the sequence they are recognized by the kernel (I have only one dongle, so I can't test). Just try it out (I found the following description: `-d <index> When using multiple dongles, this indicated which. You can also identify dongles by the text in the serial number field of the EEPROM`. Just try it ...

Comment: And I could use this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/rtl_eeprom.1.html to change serial numbers if needed mmm thanks!